# Is there any way to echo '&timestamp' in php?

Tags: php

*Code:*

```
function getShopInfo()
    {
        $url = $this->env['url'] . "shop/get?partner_id=" . $this->partner_id . "&shopid=" . $this->shop_id . "&timestamp=" . $this->getTimestamp();
        echo $url;
    }
```

*Result:*

```
https://url.com/api/v2/shop/get?partner_id=99999&shopid=123456×tamp=1613629442
```

Why the output for `&timestamp` is printed as `×tamp`?

Answer (score 2):

`&` has special meaning in HTML, it's used to start an entity specification.

Use the `htmlspecialchars()` function to encode all the special characters so you can see them literally.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($url);
```

Comment: Is this a unique question, Barmar?

Comment: I tried to find a duplicate. I found questions about `<` and `>`, but not a good one about `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, you should be using [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build URL-encoded query strings. i.e:

```php
function getShopInfo()
{
    $data = [
        "partner_id" => $this->partner_id,
        "shopid" => $this->shop_id,
        "timestamp" => $this->getTimestamp()
    ];

    $url =  $this->env['url'] . "shop/get?". http_build_query($data);
    echo $url;
}
```

Comment: That won't work if you try to use the URL with `file_get_contents()` as in the commented-out part of the code.

Comment: @Barmar I've fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This is my preferred technique because it is reliable, readable, and uses native php functions for exactly their designated purpose.